# How to convert wrappedArray column in spark dataset to java array?

Tags: java, apache-spark

In my project I got a column after applying collect_list aggregate function, which is of format wrappedArray , I wanted to know is there anyway to convert that wrappedArray to normal array or list So that I can iterate over that column and extract values row by row in that column?

Language:- JAVA
Using Apache spark library

By this I am getting that column which is of wrappedArray type

```
dataset.groupBy( "department","salary","tag")
.agg(collect_list(col("id")));
```

```
dataset.foreach(row ->
      row.getAs("id)")

);
```

I am confused how should I proceed further to iterate in that column.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `WrappedArray` there are several ways to convert it to a Java collection.
You can leverage `scala.collection.JavaConverters` helper methods:

```java
WrappedArray<Long> wrappedArray = row.getAs("ids");
List<Long> list = scala.collection.JavaConverters.seqAsJavaList(wrappedArray.seq());
```

Alternatively, you can use the `Row.getList` method to obtain directly a Java List:

```java
List<Long> list = row.getList(row.fieldIndex("ids"));
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert scala wrappedArray column to Java list in java spark.
here line is of type Row.

```
List<Long> list = scala.collection.JavaConverters.seqAsJavaList(line.getAs("fieldName")));
```